# How to write a match query OR with a prefix query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

For example if have a string "nite out" now i want my strings to match with "nite" OR match its prefix with "out", So for the above string scoring must be like at the first "nite out", "nite outing", "nite" and "out" same priority, "outing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below mention both query will match "nite out" and "nite outing"

"With Default AND Operator"

```
POST YourIndex/YourType/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "nite AND out*"
        }
    }     
}
```

"With OR Operator"

```
POST YourIndex/YourType/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "nite OR out*"
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: if i have to specify field also can u tell me where to define the fields ??

Comment: one question can u please tell what will happen if i write "query": "nite out*" i mean not specifying AND or OR.